# Is the Elvis Operator (Nullsave Dereference Operator) causing null reference exceptions?

Tags: c#, null, operators, dereference, null-coalescing-operator

When calling an extension method on an expression containing an elvis operator (i.e. the nullsafe dereferencing operator; ?.) the resulting null is not passed to the extension method as expected. In essence, it might cause unexpected null reference exceptions. Here's a program demonstrating this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nil = null;
        foreach (var c in ((nil?.ToCharArray()).EmptyIfDefault())) { }; // works
        foreach (var c in (nil?.ToCharArray().EmptyIfDefault())) { }; // nullref
    }
}

public static class Utility
{
    public static char[] EmptyIfDefault(this char[] target)
    {
        return target ?? new char[0];
    }
}
```

Does anybody if this behavior is by design? Notice there's no ? between the ToCharArray() and the EmptyIfDefault. If there was, I'd understand the current behavior. Right now, it seems like a bug. (What's the correct way to report this to Microsoft?)

For others who see the same behavior: the extra braces seem to prevent it.

(By the way: here's the actual EmptyIfNull I'm using:)

```
    public static IEnumerable<TTarget> EmptyIfNull<TTarget>(this IEnumerable<TTarget> target)
    {
        return target ?? Enumerable.Empty<TTarget>();
    }
```

*edit* I'll just include the answer given below into my question:

It is related to a common pitfall:

```
var txt = "I am " +
    age>=18 ? "mature" : "not old" +
    " enough.";
```

This is also interpreted as

```
var txt = "I am " + 
    age >= 18 
        ? "mature" 
        : ("not old" + " enough.");
```

When rewritten, The behavior without braces makes sense:

```
foreach(var c in 
    nil == null
        ? null
        : nil.ToCharArray().EmptyIfDefault()) { }; // nullref
```

Comment: `elvis operator` never heard that before, but I like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's unintuitive at first, it definitely is not a bug. You're getting a `NullReferenceException` because you're trying to iterate over `null` (it's not throwing the exception while evaluating the expressions)

Let's look at this example:

```
var t = nil?.ToCharArray().EmptyIfNull();
```

The above will *not* call `EmptyIfNull`, because `nil` will be `null` and the method chain will short-circuit to return `null`.

That is, we can write the above as:

```
IEnumerable<char> t;
if (nil != null)
    t = nil.ToCharArray().EmptyIfNull();
else
    t = null;
```

Note that the `EmptyIfNull` *only* executes if the initial condition passes (that is, `nil` is not null).

Now, why do brackets fix it?

```
var t = (nil?.ToCharArray()).EmptyIfNull();
```

This can be re-written as:

```
IEnumerable<char> t;
IEnumerable<char> temp;
if (nil != null)
    temp = nil.ToCharArray();
else
    temp = null;
t = temp.EmptyIfNull();
```

See that the short-circuiting behavior only applies to the inner expression - and then we *always* call `EmptyIfNull` on the result.

Comment: Ah, so it has to do with operator precedense. The "dot-operator" (I'll just call it that) takes precedense over the "null dereferincing operator".

var t = nil == null ? null : nil.toCharArray().EmptyIfNull()